# Hadoop installation error when formatting NameNode

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I'm installing hadoop on remote server(centos) I've installed hadoop successfully in local mode and trying to install it in `pseudo-distributed` mode but after all the configuration changes in `core-site.xml` and `mapred-site.xml` when i run
`hdfs namenode -format` i get following errors:

[image]

Comment: What's is the error you are getting..?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an `UnknownHostException` which means it can't resolve the hostname to an IP address.

You can probably fix this by either:

1. Change references to that hostname to `localhost` in the configuration files
2. Add a lookup to the hostname in the hosts file located at `/etc/hosts`